# Make C# Dependency only trigger when new rows have been inserted into MS SQL with specific column value

Tags: c#, sql-server, dependencies

I want to receive a "change" event when new rows have been inserted into MS SQL with specific column value.

Below is the code I currently use, which works fairly well, except that it triggers an event when any row value in [Status] column changes to/ OR from "NEW".

```
public void InitialiseDependencyWORK(Action onDependencyMethod)
{

    this.onDependencyMethod = onDependencyMethod;

    string sqlCommandText = "SELECT [Symbol] FROM [JJ].[Orders] WHERE [Status] = 'NEW'";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText, conn))
    {

        Dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

        Dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Process the DataReader.
        }
    }

}

void OnDependencyChange(object sender,
   SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    // Handles NEW rows
}
```

I am only interested when a new row is inserted with [Status] = "NEW", but this event also triggers when there is no new insert BUT [Status] has changed from "NEW" to anything else.

How can I only get a trigger event when there has been a new insert?

I would like to receive a trigger event when news rows have been inserted like row 2 below:

```
OrderID, Status 
1,Done 
2,NEW
```

I DON'T want it to trigger because row 2 has just had its Status updated - there is actually no new row to process:

```
OrderID, Status
1,Done
2,Done
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why delete your old [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55340609/how-can-i-set-c-sharp-dependency-to-only-fire-if-new-rows?noredirect=1#comment97406334_55340609) and duplicate it? This doesn't add anything to the previous question you had.

Comment: Question restructured to give better explanation of my issue

Comment: You could check specifically for inserts in you handler with `if(e.Info == "Insert")`, ignoring others and resubscribe.

Comment: @DanGuzman What would e.Info return if there where a host of updates and changes?

Answer (score 3):

The general use case of using `SqlDependency` is for detecting changes to data that doesn't change very often that you would like to cache, but also need to know if it does change so you can refresh the cache without polling the database.  Your case is slightly different in that you don't really want to know when the results of that query changes... you want to know when a certain query contains results to process.  The reason you're getting the notification when the status code changes to AND from "NEW" is because both of those types of changes will alter the query results.  It is adding and subtracting entire rows based on both kinds of change.

If you are only using the status codes "NEW" and "DONE" and they are guaranteed to always initiate as "NEW" and progress only forward to "DONE" (and never back), then a workaround might be to use this query:

```
SELECT [OrderID] FROM [JJ].[Orders] WHERE [Status] <= 'NEW'
```

This way a new item added in status "NEW" will change the query results... but when it moves to "DONE" it will still be an `OrderID` returned in the query and should not trigger a change event.  If you have more status values you progress though... you might consider using an integer in your status column to indicate the progression.  For example 0 for new, 1 for in progress, 2 done... etc.

It sounds like you are trying to create some kind of queue of work to be done and there are other ways to do that sort of thing also.  There is SQL Server Change Tracking and Data Change Tracking, Triggers, Service Broker Queues, and lots of other queuing technologies.  You might check into them as well as options for your architecture.

Answer (score 2):

May I ask why you are reinventing SQL triggers in c# for context? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

The simplest solution is to capture this at the table itself and not via a query which will yield false positives.

Alternatively if you are running all of your code via a repository layer then you should be able to differentiate an INSERT from an UPDATE and pick it off there too.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by reineventing. I am USING c# functionality to receive an event trigger within my c# application, as it is the application that wants to do something on an insert event. Can I use your suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response ManInMoon. 
If the only possible path for edits is through your application and you have a business logic layer or repository pattern in which all edits run through that single point you could preemptively determine edits prior to them taking place as noted previously. This is sketchy to me as you are locking into the thought that you will only ever allow changes through that single point.This is of course ideal, but you must ensure that all edits to that data only occur via that single point. At the table level you are assured to capture it.

Answer (score 2):

I think SqlDependency event fire whenever there is any Insert/Update/Delete in Table.

There is no way of stopping it.

you can catch the appropriate notification type in event and do you work.

```
void OnDependencyChange(object sender,
   SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert)
}
```

Other Way of doing it which I hvn't tried,

Create another table `OrdersCopy`  which is replica of `[JJ].[Orders]`

Create Insert Trigger in Order table.

Whenever there is insert in Order table,trigger will fire.
Insert the new record in `OrdersCopy`

Here do the following change, change the table name to `OrderCopy`

```
string sqlCommandText = "SELECT [Symbol] FROM [JJ].[OrdersCopy] WHERE [Status] = 'NEW'";
```

For experiment shake,you can try this once.

`OnDependencyChange` event will only fire in case of Insert.